# how to write regex to match any value in jsonpath for particular key?

Tags: java, regex, jsonpath

I have below the JSON structure. In which I am trying to find the value based on jsonpath.

```
 {
   "business": {
    "BusinessUnit": "78sdhja",
    "PriorityType": "Scheduled",
    "NoPhiScrubbing": "false"
}
}
```

Here, I am trying to get the business unit which can have any value like can be empty or null or any value. 
I have tried with the below example. But it didn't work.

```
"$.business.[?(@.BusinessUnit== /.*/)]";
```

Can anyone help me to with this?

Comment: Don't use regexpr on complex data structures unless you really really have to. There are tools (jackson, gson...) that are way better than any regexpr you can possibly come up with.

Comment: it is not possible to get it using regex like how i have wriiten? because I have use case where i need to find value having any string using JSON path?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Spring based project. Go with JSR Validations

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-bean-validation-example-with-jsr-303-annotations/

https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/

Above link will help

For Not null or empty you can use @NotNull @Empty while for any value validation you may use **pattern** for same.

In case value doesn't match, it throws **MethodArgumentNotValidException**